# Why does a MemoryStream throw an InvalidFormatException?

Tags: c#

I have the following lines of code

```
var input = "<x";
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var test = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
ms.Write(test, 0, test.Length);
var sut = new Web.Transpiler.Transpiler();
var rs = await sut.TranspileAsync(ms);
```

The last line throws a FormatException with the following in the stack.

```
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Byte.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at MyProject.Transpiler.<TranspileAsync>d__4.MoveNext() 
in C:\Users\thala\Documents\Projects\my-project\MyProject\Transpiler\Transpiler.cs:line 22
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like the parsing code in `Transpiler` is expecting a number but the input string is NOT a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing to a memory stream, you should [seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) the start again when reading from it, like so:

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Though I guess it's your Transpiler throwing the invalidoperation exception

Comment: Interesting.  The first line of the TranspileAsync code has a Byte.Parse() statement which turns out to be the problem.  The method returns when I step into it.  I don't understand why the error doesn't occur on the Byte.Parse() statement.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is trying to convert your input to a number, I'm not sure what the Transpiler is as the stack trace seems to point to your code, but it is trying to convert a String to a number.

```
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Byte.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at MyProject.Transpiler.<TranspileAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
```

Looks like there is a `Byte.Parse` or similar code in there.

I suggest you have a look at Visual Studio's Exception settings and set "Break on CLR Exceptions" to "ON" to get the debugger to break on the line with the problem.